# How to check if a variable exists in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

In flex, how to check if a variable exists? I have tried using

```
if (this['some_variable'] != undefined) {
    //do something
}
```

There is a run time error saying the property `some_variable` does not exists. I have checked with `null` instead of `undefined`, still the same error.

please help.

**[EDIT]**

Based on the replies I have used `this.hasOwnProperty('variable_name')`. I found that its returning `true` if `variable_name` is a `public` but `false` if its `private/protected`. How to check for a private variable?

Comment: set a breakpoint and check the Variables view - assuming you're using Flash Builder.

Comment: hasOwnProperty() only works for those fields that are made public. There is nothing you can do in AS3 to perform intraspection to reveal private members. If this absolutely a requirement for you, switch over to AS2 where everything is public.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
if (this. hasOwnProperty("some_variable")) {
    //access the variable inside
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways for that:

```
if ("some_variable" in this) {
    //do something
}
```

It uses [`in` operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#in).

And:

```
if (this.hasOwnProperty("some_variable")) {
    //do something
}
```

See [documentation about `hasOwnProperty()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#hasOwnProperty%28%29).

What about getting information about private/protected properties the situation is that you can't get this info with the current state of Flash Player. The only possible way, I suppose, is some kind of runtime bytecode manipulation. But as far as I know nobody implemented it yet.

But I have a question about getting info about private/protected properties: for what purpose you need it? The nature of these properties/methods is you can't call them. Even if you know about their existence.

Comment: Only `if ("some_variable" in ClassName)` works with static fields.

Answer (score 2):

`if (this.hasOwnProperty('some_variable')) DO_IT_!()`

Explanation:

`this['some_variable']` tries to evaluate the value of the instance property `some_variable`. If there is no such a property, you will get this error.

To test if a property exists for a particular object use `hasOwnProperty` or wrap your condition in a `try/catch` block or use `if ('some_variable' in this)`.

Usually you create an object property in a class file:

```
public class MyClass {
   public var myProperty : String = "ich bin hier";
}
```

Then you refer to that property within the class:

```
trace (myProperty);
trace (this.myProperty);
```

Using the array syntax [] is also possible but will throw the error if the property is not defined.

```
trace (this['myProperty']);
```

And finally! If you declare your class to be dynamic you might use the array syntax even if the property does not exist.

```
public dynamic class MyClass {
   public function MyClass() {
       trace (this["never_declared_property"]);
   }
}
```